# Handling of faulty ISO7816 APDUs

Tags: iso, javacard

Are there any specifications in the Java Card API, RE or VM specs as to how the card *must* react to faulty ISO7816-4 APDUs (provided that such malformed APDUs are passed to the card at all)?

Are there different requirements for the APDU handling of applets?

If I were to send e.g. a (faulty) 3-byte long first interindustry APDU to the
card/applet - who should detect/report this error?

Who would detect/report a first interindustry APDU containing a bad LC
length field?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no generic specification that defines how to handle malformed APDU's.

In general you should always return a status word that is in a valid ISO 7816-3/4 range. Which one depends fully on the context. Generally you should try always to throw an `ISOException` with a logical status word on error conditions.  You should try never to return a `6F00` status word, which is returned if the `Applet.process()` method exits with an exception other than `ISOException`. The most common (not *all*) ISO status words have been defined in the `ISO7816` interface.

Unfortunately, ISO 7816-4 only provides some hints regarding which status words may be expected. On the other hand, unless the error is very specific (e.g. incorrect PIN), there is not too much a terminal can do if it receives a status word on a *syntactically* incorrect APDU (it is unlikely to fix an incorrect APDU command data field). Any specific status words should be defined by higher level protocols. ISO 7816-4 itself can only be used as a (rotten) foundation for other protocols. No clear rules for handling syntactic (wrong length) or semantic (wrong PIN) errors have been defined.

With regard to malformed APDU's: 3 byte APDU's won't be received by the Applet. Bytes with an incorrect Lc byte may be received. It would however be more logical if this would influence the transport layer in such a way that the transport layer either times out because it is expecting more data, or that spurious bytes are discarded. It cannot hurt to check and return a wrong length error, but please use the values of `APDU.getIncomingLength()` or `APDU.setIncomingAndReceive()` as final values for Ne if you decide to continue.

Comment: I'm afraid my question was not that precise.

Comment: In general I'm interested in who (terminal, card, applet) has to deal with which kind of erroneous APDUs.
You already stated that a 3-byte APDU won't get through to the applet but would it get through to the card or already be caught by the terminal? Are there any specs that specify exactly this assignment of responsibilities?

Comment: @ThomasLieven that depends on the implementation and error handling of the transport layer protocol by both the terminal and - possibly -  the card. In practice, I guess you cannot say much about it. 3 byte commands should not be handled by Java Card applets though - it has been specified in the Java Card specifications and those are particularly strict.